# Fgetcsv with loop and get the correct value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a txt file and I need to upload it in my mysql db. So I found this code in php.net:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

It worked. When I gave a 'print_r' I have this:

```
PAGE:1
ANUALDATA
Ver:1.651.A
Site data ou www.sitedata.com
COUNT:3758-3 NAME:USER NAME IDUS: 262.911.258-62
PLACE:030 IDCUS:11003 
DATE 31/12/2011
VALUE................................U$ 200,00
PROCESS DATE 31/12/2011
VALUE NEEDED.....................U$ 3,45
PAID VALUE..........U$ 50,00
PAGE:2
ANUALDATA
Ver:1.651.A
Site data ou www.sitedata.com
COUNT:3758-3 NAME:USER NAME IDUS: 262.911.258-62
PLACE:030 IDCUS:11003 
DATE 31/12/2011
VALUE................................U$ 200,00
PROCESS DATE 31/12/2011
VALUE NEEDED.....................U$ 3,45
PAID VALUE..........U$ 50,00
PAGE:3
ANUALDATA
Ver:1.651.A
Site data ou www.sitedata.com
COUNT:3758-3 NAME:USER NAME IDUS: 262.911.258-62
PLACE:030 IDCUS:11003 
DATE 31/12/2011
VALUE................................U$ 200,00
PROCESS DATE 31/12/2011
VALUE NEEDED.....................U$ 3,45
PAID VALUE..........U$ 50,00
```

Now comes my problem. I saw others examples but really could use it into my case.
I need to do something like transform each line in $key = $val, like

```
[VALUE] => 200,00
[PROCESS DATE] =>31/12/2011
```

And you will notice that are pages, I need to brake it to have something like this

```
[0]
    [VALUE] => 200,00
    [PROCESS DATE] =>31/12/2011
[1]
    [VALUE] => 200,00
    [PROCESS DATE] =>31/12/2011
```

So, I will insert this data in each row in db. Is there a way?
If I could get only de $value it will be ok too.

Edit

It is not an CSV, it is an TXT that another system creates and I don´t have control over it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the multiple `:`'s in `COUNT:3758-3 NAME:USER NAME IDUS: 262.911.258-62`?

Comment: I will separate too. I used 'value' and 'process data' just as an example

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is the result of the code snippet, I cant see the printout of `echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";`. Also it seem the delimiter is ":" (assuming it does not occur anywhere else in the text). That said, try this...

```
$row = 1;
$res = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        $tmpArr = array();
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            list($key, $val) = explode(":", $data[$c]);
            $tmpArr[$key] = $val;
        }
        $res[] = $tmpArr;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: I got this error:  'Undefined offset: 1' in the line of the explode. Found that is because an empty line, but don't know where...Could you help?

Comment: Just edit the for loop and replace the content with...
     if(isset($data[$c]) && strstr($data[$c], ':') {
         list($key, $val) = explode(":", $data[$c]);
         $tmpArr[$key] = $val;
     }

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get it loaded into MySQL, have you looked into LOAD DATA INFILE?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: I saw it, but I can´t see how to separete the data.

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from the CSV itself?